# PHP - Take file from different input fields, but to the same arrray

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, dom

I am designing a website for Real Estate agency, in my form I am taking several "Floor Plan"s.

In the form, there is a "Add Floor Plan Button", and this button ads a input field for taking a floor plan(1 image and 1 name for floor plan)

This is the form(Do not mind the `<form>` element):

```
<div class="floorPlan">
        <label for="floorPlanPhoto" class="form-label">Floor Plan Photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="floorPlanPhoto[]" id="floorPlanPhoto" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="floorPlanName" class="form-label mt-1 mb-1">Kat Plan Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="floorPlanName" id="floorPlanName" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

As I mentioned before, user can add several floor plans. So, in my `<div class="floorPlans"></div>` there can be more than 1 input field for adding floor plan.

If user adds only 1 floor plan and submits the form, floor plan is saved as I want(photo is saved and renamed as plan name). But if user adds 2 or more plans, only last one is saved.

When user is submitting, the field `floorPlanPhoto[]` is rewritten, not appended I think. This is the probably reason. So I should save into `floorPlanPhoto[]` multiple photos

How can I do that, or any other algorithms to do this?

PS: I do not WANT to take multiple(I mean one input area with multiple tag) images in input field . User should add floor plan as much as he/she wants(1 image and 1 name).

This is the code for saving files:

```
if(isset($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"])){
    $images = $_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"];
    $imagesCount = count($images["name"]);
    $floorPlanName = $_POST["floorPlanName"];
    
    if (!file_exists("projects/" . $projectlink . "/floorplans")) {
        mkdir("projects/" . $projectlink . "/floorplans");
    }
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $imagesCount; $i++) {
        $targetDir = "projects/" . $projectlink . "/floorplans/";
        $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"]["name"][$i]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
        //Check if the image file is actually image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
        if ($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $errors["imageError"] = "Error ";
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"]["tmp_name"][$i], $targetFile)) {
                $errors["imageSuccess"] = "Success!";
                rename($targetFile, $targetDir . $floorPlanName . ".jpg");
            } else {
                $errors["imageError"] = "Error.";
            }
        }
    
        print_r($errors);
    }
```

GIF - Adding a floor plan field (As you see, user clicks the button and new field is added to the page. So that user can submit an image for the plan and name for it.):
[image]

var_dump[$_FILES](when 2 floor plans submitted)

```
array(2) { 
    ["projectImages"]=> array(6) { 
        ["name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(5) "2.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(5) "3.jpg" 
        } 
        ["full_path"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(5) "2.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(5) "3.jpg" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
            [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5A1.tmp" 
            [1]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B2.tmp" 
        } 
        ["error"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            [1]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["size"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(390388) 
            [1]=> int(231082) 
        } 
    } 
    ["floorPlanPhoto"]=> array(6) { 
        ["name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(8) "plan.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(9) "plan2.jpg" 
        } 
        ["full_path"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(8) "plan.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(9) "plan2.jpg" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
            [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B3.tmp" 
            [1]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B4.tmp" 
        } 
        ["error"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            [1]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["size"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(53386) 
            [1]=> int(58397) 
        } 
    }
} 

array(2) { 
    ["projectImages"]=> array(6) { 
        ["name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(5) "2.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(5) "3.jpg" 
        } 
        ["full_path"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(5) "2.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(5) "3.jpg" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
            [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5A1.tmp" 
            [1]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B2.tmp" 
        } 
        ["error"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            [1]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["size"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(390388) 
            [1]=> int(231082) 
        } 
    } 
    ["floorPlanPhoto"]=> array(6) { 
        ["name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(8) "plan.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(9) "plan2.jpg" 
        } 
        ["full_path"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(8) "plan.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(9) "plan2.jpg" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
            [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B3.tmp" 
            [1]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B4.tmp" 
        } 
        ["error"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            [1]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["size"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> int(53386) 
            [1]=> int(58397) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The JavaScript code works on Button Click to add input field for floor plan:

```
var floorPlanField = `
        <label for="floorPlanPhoto" class="form-label">Kat Planı Fotoğrafı</label>
        <input type="file" name="floorPlanPhoto[]" id="floorPlanPhoto" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="floorPlanName" class="form-label mt-1 mb-1">Kat Planı İsmi</label>
        <input type="text" name="floorPlanName" id="floorPlanName" class="form-control" required>
        <button class="btn btn-danger mt-1 mb-1 removeFloorPlanArea">Kaldır</button>`;

var addFloorPlanButton = document.getElementById("addFloorPlan");
var floorPlans = document.getElementsByClassName("floorPlans")[0];

addFloorPlanButton.addEventListener("click", addFloorPlan);

function addFloorPlan() {
    var floorPlan = document.createElement("div");
    floorPlan.classList.add("floorPlan");
    floorPlan.innerHTML = floorPlanField;
    var created = floorPlans.appendChild(floorPlan);
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($_FILES['floorPlanPhoto'])`?

Comment: Are these all in the same `<form>`?

Comment: _user can add several floor plans. So, in my <div class="floorPlans"></div> there can be more than 1 input field for adding floor plan._ **So why not show us what you mean by that in your example code**

Comment: _If_ the inputs in your `<div class="floorPlan">` get duplicated you'll end up with multiple identical `id`s - which is invalid, `id`s must be unique.

Comment: If you were to spend a few minutes reading the [PHP File Upload Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) You would find out how to use the $_FILES array to find **1)** if the file was successfully uploaded **2)** The size of the file uploaded **3)** An Error field and info on what each error code means. **etc etc etc** Rather than re-inventing the wheel and making a less than perfect job of it

Comment: I fix the ID's, but thats not the point guys.

Comment: Pretty moving pictures! But that does not show the HTML being generated by your javascript that must be being run to add the additional file & name sets.

Comment: **Start by showing us** the output from a `var_dump($_FILES)` so we can see what has been sent when you have tried to incude multiple file and name sets

Comment: How do you submit the form, via a regular button or is Javascript involved?

Comment: @brombeer Regular form.

Comment: You might also consider the old premis, if I want other peoples help, the least I can do is spend a moment making sure the **data I present is at least readable**

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, I forgot to check it. My fault. Thanks for formatting.

Comment: Your JS is creating `<input type="text" name="floorPlanName" .....` Always with the same `name="floorPlanName"` so there will only ever be ONE returned to the PHP backend

Comment: Why are you doing this `rename($targetFile, $targetDir . $floorPlanName . ".jpg");` Instead PUT THE RIGHT NAME INTO the `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly First, I am moving the file into it is related location, then rename the file with the plan name, to prevent any random file name.

Comment: Except ALL your files will ALL be called the same as you will only ever habe one `name="floorPlanName"` returned to the backend

Comment: @RiggsFolly Okay, I will try to handle it on the JS side.

Comment: No, give all the names a unique `name=` or use an array for that as well

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I make the names unique on the JS side because they are created there.

Comment: @NicoHaase thought it was a PHP problem, But it turns out it is a JS problem. I shared my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

> @RiggisFolly :
> "Except ALL your files will ALL be called the same as you will only ever habe one name="floorPlanName" returned to the backend"

So, I modify the JavaScript code to make names different

```
//first approach, it WORKS
var addFloorPlanButton = document.getElementById("addFloorPlan");
var floorPlans = document.getElementsByClassName("floorPlans")[0];

addFloorPlanButton.addEventListener("click", addFloorPlan);

let totalFloorPlan = 1;

function addFloorPlan() {
  var floorPlan = document.createElement("div");
  floorPlan.classList.add("floorPlan");
  floorPlan.innerHTML = createInputField(`floorPlanName${totalFloorPlan}`);
  totalFloorPlan++;
  var created = floorPlans.appendChild(floorPlan);
  var removeFloorPlanButton = created.getElementsByClassName("removeFloorPlanArea")[0];
  removeFloorPlanButton.addEventListener("click", removeFloorPlan);
}

function createInputField(name) {
  var floorPlanField = `
        <label for="floorPlanPhoto" class="form-label">Kat Planı Fotoğrafı</label>
        <input type="file" name="floorPlanPhoto[]" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="floorPlanName" class="form-label mt-1 mb-1">Kat Planı İsmi</label>
        <input type="text" name="${name}" class="form-control" required>
        <button class="btn btn-danger mt-1 mb-1 removeFloorPlanArea">Kaldır</button>
    `;
  return floorPlanField;
```

And, a mini update for my file handler in the backend:

```
if(isset($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"])){
            $images = $_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"];
            $imagesCount = count($images["name"]);
            
            if (!file_exists("projects/" . $projectlink . "/floorplans")) {
                mkdir("projects/" . $projectlink . "/floorplans");
            }
            
            for ($i = 0; $i < $imagesCount; $i++) {
                $floorPlanName = $_POST["floorPlanName" . $i+1]; //Take the plan name for every file -change is here-
                $targetDir = "projects/" . $projectlink . "/floorplans/";
                $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"]["name"][$i]);
                $uploadOk = 1;
                $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
                if ($check !== false) {
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                    $errors["imageError"] = "Error";
                } else {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["floorPlanPhoto"]["tmp_name"][$i], $targetFile)) {
                        $errors["imageSuccess"] = "Success";
                        rename($targetFile, $targetDir . $floorPlanName . ".jpg");
                    } else {
                        $errors["imageError"] = "Error.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And that takes every single image and name and manipulates on the backend.